# didSelectRowAtIndexPath with a tableView that has sections

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView with several section and each section contains only one cell (this is done to create a gab between each cell). Im trying to create a custom selection view for my cell when it is selected. 
when I select a row, the custom selection view is being added to more than one cell. I know the problem is because cells are being reused. What is the best suitable solution to overcome this problem?

This is my code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if let myCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? PredefinedServicesCell{
            let selectionView = UIView()
            selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0x3399CC).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
            selectionView.layer.cornerRadius = (myCell.containerView.layer.cornerRadius)
            selectionView.frame = (myCell.containerView.frame)
            myCell.containerView.addSubview(selectionView)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maintain the appropriate parameters in the **model** (data source array) and reload the table **view** at given index path accordingly. For example add a boolean property `selected` and add or remove the subview in the delegate method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Why don't you simply set the cell's backgroundColor instead of adding another view?

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath and after getting the cell from reuse, check if it is not selected hide your custom select view, and  when your selection changed you should reload your tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make you custom selected view hide or show in the following method in your CustomCell Class

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.customSelectedView.hidden = !selected
}
```

Comment: im creating the custom view programmatically in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You can make base class of `UITableViewCell` instead for a good approach